# How to add multiple terms in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I recieve a requirement where I have to add multiple Terms and custom text in google map footer. 
Below is the format that I am trying to achieve:

**Map data ©2017 GfK GeoMarketing | Terms | Google, INEGI, ORION-ME | Terms | [distance scale]**

Please suggest me.

I am using normal javascript code to create google map and below are the code :

```
   var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 3,
        styles: [
            {
                featureType: "all",
                stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
                ]
            },
            { "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }, { "opacity": "0.1" }] },
            { "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }] }
        ],
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -87.5),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        backgroundColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0)',
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy'
       // zoomControlOptions: {
        //    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
       // }
    };
    nimbus.tileMgr.overlappedmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.overtlayMapId), mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because it violates Terms of Service of Google Maps API. Please have a look at paragraphs 9.4 (a) and 10.5 (g) of ToS. They read:

> Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google, its strategic partners, or other third-party rights holders of content that Google indexes. When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, you **must display such attribution as provided** (or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation) and **must not delete or alter the attribution**.
>
> **No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or proprietary rights notices.** You will not:
> remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms, or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices; or
> falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other labels of the origin or source of material.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#10-license-restrictions